# Where can I get Force.com IDE plugin version 26

Tags: force.com, ide

I can't seem to find a list of old versions.

Comment: Why do you want it ? Maybe there's a different solution to what you truly want to get done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Eclipse you can follow the normal Force.com IDE Plugin instructions, except you can choose to not *Show only the latest versions of available software*.

1. Help | Install New Software...
2. Click Add.. button to add a new site.
3. Call It Force.com IDE and give it the value of http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/ and click OK.
4. Untick the Show only the latest versions of available software

Expand the Force.com IDE node and you'll see that there are the previous versions

[image]

Alternatively you can go directly to the previous version (26) by using the site URL of http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/previous.